# ListView item onClickListener and garbage collector

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView and an ArrayAdapter. In method getView I create button on each list element.
Here is my code for the method `onClick`

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, audioResourceId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_mic_pressed);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_mic);
        }
    });
}
```

So if I click a button, and scroll to the bottom of the list, the sounds get interrupted. I think it is interrupted because this List Item is out of screen and is garbage collected.

How I can make this sound play till the end, even if I scroll ListView to bottom, or switch views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a separate thread which holds your `MediaPlayer` object. When you click on the button, send a message to that thread telling it what audio resource you want to play.

The easiest way to do this is probably using an [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) object, which will manage your thread and create a message queue for communicating with it.

Comment: i thought to make something like static method where i can give my sound, what i want to play. This will not work?

Comment: Yes, that will fix your immediate problem. But as a general rule, any "heavy lifting" should not be done on the UI thread. Even if it works, this behavior will often cause sluggish performance. Without looking at the MediaPlayer internals, it's best to just assume the worst. (If you really want to test, you can turn on Strict Mode for your application, which will warn you of any blocking I/O on the UI thread.)

Comment: And what for i need Handler? Can i just onClick create MyThread instance (which can play sound) and start() it?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. However, using a Handler simplifies a lot of common usage patterns -- in particular, it makes it much easier to update the UI if you need to.

Comment: i run my player in separate Thread, from that thread sending Handler a message to Update UI, but sound still interrupted when i lost my view.

Comment: Clearly something important is still getting deallocated when you're scrolling. Check the scope of your variables. There's no reason a separate thread should be affected by anything happening on the UI (unless you're explicitly sending a message to the other thread).